# ncurses library I want to know why colors cannot be drawn

Tags: c++

[I'm Japanese using google translate]

The presentation code is `void Renderer ();` the function part, why can't I draw the color? I don't know the cause.

Also, the `addch ();` function can draw colors normally.

#### OS：　Ubuntu

Reference site　A:　https://www.linuxjournal.com/content/programming-color-ncurses

Reference site　B:　https://www.linuxjournal.com/content/about-ncurses-colors-0

Screen.cpp

```
#include "../header/Screen.hpp"


#include "../header/Character.hpp"
#include "../header/Color.hpp"
#include "../header/Vector.hpp"
#include "../header/Screen.hpp"



//　######################## コンストラクタ ######################## 
Screen::Screen()
{

      //ウインドウ初期化
    getmaxyx(stdscr,windowSize.y,windowSize.x);
    window = newpad(windowSize.y,windowSize.x);
    start_color();              //カラーを有効化

    prefresh(window,0,0,0,0,windowSize.y,windowSize.x);


      size.x = windowSize.x;
      size.y = windowSize.y;
      maxSize = size.x * size.y;

      stage = std::make_unique<std::vector<Character>>(size.x * size.y);
      
      for(std::vector<Character>::iterator itr = stage->begin(); itr != stage->end(); itr++)
      {
            itr->chr = ' ';
            itr->color = Color::NONE;
            itr->type = 0;
      }
}



//　######################## 画面サイズ更新 ########################
void Screen::UpdateScreen()
{
      //画面サイズを取得
      getmaxyx(stdscr,windowSize.y,windowSize.x);
      
      //前のウインドウサイズをより大きければ要素を代入
      if((windowSize.x * windowSize.y) > maxSize) 
      {
            maxSize = windowSize.x * windowSize.y;
            size.x = windowSize.x;
            size.y = windowSize.y;

            for(int i = 0; i< (windowSize.x * windowSize.y); i++)
            {
                  stage->emplace_back(Character{Color::NONE,' ',0});
            }
      }
}



//　######################## Update ########################
void Screen::Update()
{
      UpdateScreen();   //画面サイズを更新
}

//　######################## 文字設定 ######################## 
void Screen::Input(int x,int y,Character c)
{
      stage->at((y * size.x) + x) = c;
}

//　######################## 文字削除 ######################## 
void Screen::Delete(int x,int y)
{
      stage->at((y * size.x) + x).chr = ' ';
      stage->at((y * size.x) + x).color = Color::NONE;
      stage->at((y * size.x) + x).type = 0;
}

//　######################## Renderer ######################## 
void Screen::Renderer()const
{

      for(int y = 0; y < size.y; y++)
      {
            for(int x = 0; x < size.x; x++)
            {
//              attron(COLOR_PAIR(stage->at((y * size.x) + x).color));
                attron(COLOR_PAIR(16));

                  mvwaddch(window,y,x,stage->at((y * size.x) + x).chr);
                  //addch(stage->at((y * size.x) + x).chr);
                //attrset(COLOR_PAIR(16));

                //attroff(stage->at((y * size.x) + x).type);
//              attroff(COLOR_PAIR(stage->at((y * size.x) + x).color));
            }
      }

    prefresh(window,0,0,0,0,windowSize.y,windowSize.x);      
}

//　######################## デストラクタ ######################## 
Screen::~Screen()
{


}
```

Comment: I was able to check if my terminal could use color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
wattron(window,COLOR_PAIR(stage->at((y * size.x) + 
wattroff(window,COLOR_PAIR(stage->at((y * size.x) +
```

When using windows, it was necessary to use the `wattron()` and `wattroff()` functions instead of the `attron()` and `attroff()` functions.

The code inside the comment part of the question sentence needs to be modified as follows for the for statement.

```
    for(int y = 0; y < size.y; y++)
      {
            for(int x = 0; x < size.x; x++)
            {
                  wattron(window,COLOR_PAIR(stage->at((y * size.x) + x).color));

                  mvwaddch(window,y,x,stage->at((y * size.x) + x).chr);
                  
                  wattroff(window,COLOR_PAIR(stage->at((y * size.x) + x).color));

            }
      }
```